How to protect a painted side table that will get a lot of wear and tear?
I have painted a wood side table. The table will get a lot of use.
What can I coat the table with to protect the paint?

You could get a piece of tempered glass the same size as the top of the table, along with the little plastic pads that go under glass for tables.

Polyurethane, the same stuff as they use on hardwood floors.
You want two or three coats with fine(180/220) sandpaper between coats.
